# if_else for deleting first row in each group - dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Hers is a DF for test:

```
test_df <- structure(list(plant_id = c("plant_1", "plant_1", "plant_1", "plant_1", "plant_1",
                                       "plant_2", "plant_2", "plant_2", "plant_2", "plant_2", 
                                       "plant_3", "plant_3", "plant_3", "plant_3", "plant_3",
                                       "plant_4", "plant_4", "plant_4", "plant_4", "plant_4"), 
                          skipped = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 
                                      0, 1, 1, 0, 2,
                                      1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 
                                      0, 0, 1, 1, 2)), 
                     row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame", 
                     .Names = c("plant_sp", "skipped"))
```

As you can see, variable **skipped** has the values "0", "1" or "2".
I need that per each plant_id (which is the group_by variable),
that when its' first rows are "1" at **skipped** column, row will be deleted until a change at **skipped** column.

for example in my DF:

```
   plant_sp skipped
1   plant_1       1
2   plant_1       1
3   plant_1       0
4   plant_1       1
5   plant_1       2
6   plant_2       0
7   plant_2       1
8   plant_2       1
9   plant_2       0
10  plant_2       2
11  plant_3       1
12  plant_3       0
13  plant_3       1
14  plant_3       2
15  plant_3       2
16  plant_4       0
17  plant_4       0
18  plant_4       1
19  plant_4       1
20  plant_4       2
```

TO:

```
   plant_sp skipped
   plant_sp skipped

3   plant_1       0
4   plant_1       1
5   plant_1       2
6   plant_2       0
7   plant_2       1
8   plant_2       1
9   plant_2       0
10  plant_2       2
12  plant_3       0
13  plant_3       1
14  plant_3       2
15  plant_3       2
16  plant_4       0
17  plant_4       0
18  plant_4       1
19  plant_4       1
20  plant_4       2
```

As you can see, since group "planet_1" and group "planet_2" started with "1", all rows with "1" at variable ***skipped*** at the begining were deleted (rows 1 and 2). All other rows stayed as they are.

if it is possible, a dplyr solution would be great,
Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: how are the columns getting sorted? And also could you explain the logic of removing rows a bit further, are you trying to remove rows whtere `skipped = 1` per group?

Comment: `test_df %>% group_by(plant_sp) %>% distinct(skipped) %>% ungroup()`? Might or might not be what you need depending on whether you're okay with a random row being left as the representative for all sets of rows that are duplicated.

Comment: the values at "skipped" column indicates a group of values in another one. I need that each row per group that starts with "1" at the beggining will be deleted until there is a chagne at the value. other rows will stay as they are

Comment: Would it be ok if we have two `2` in a row? I mean the only problem is with starting a group with 1 probably following with another 1?

Comment: If a group starts with 0 or 2 its ok. If it starts with "1" than it is a problem and I need to delete all rows until there is no "1" at the begining (other "1"s are ok if they are not at the begining). In my test DF, the problem is only with group 1 and 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: Original version didn't satisfy the query it has been updated now to remove only the rows including a one before a non-one entry. This matches the output presented in the query.

To try and complete this I have created some temporary rows to identify the first row which doesn't contain a one in each group and then removed all rows before this

```r
library(tidyverse)

test_df <- structure(list(plant_id = c("plant_1", "plant_1", "plant_1", "plant_1", "plant_1",
                                       "plant_2", "plant_2", "plant_2", "plant_2", "plant_2", 
                                       "plant_3", "plant_3", "plant_3", "plant_3", "plant_3",
                                       "plant_4", "plant_4", "plant_4", "plant_4", "plant_4"), 
                          skipped = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 
                                      0, 1, 1, 0, 2,
                                      1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 
                                      0, 0, 1, 1, 2)), 
                     row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame", 
                     .Names = c("plant_sp", "skipped"))

test_df <- tibble(test_df)

first_positions_df<- test_df %>% 
  # group by each factor we want
  group_by(plant_sp) %>%
  # label the order of the rows
  mutate(order = 1:length(skipped)) %>% 
  # mark position of rows which aren't a 1 otherwise set to infinity
  mutate(notones = ifelse(skipped != 1, order, Inf)) %>% 
  # Find the first position which is not a 1
  mutate(ignore = min(notones)) %>% 
  # Remove all ones before this row
  filter(ignore <= order)

#Final result
first_positions_df %>% 
  # select only the useful columns
  select(plant_sp, skipped)
#> # A tibble: 17 x 2
#> # Groups:   plant_sp [4]
#>    plant_sp skipped
#>    <chr>      <dbl>
#>  1 plant_1        0
#>  2 plant_1        1
#>  3 plant_1        2
#>  4 plant_2        0
#>  5 plant_2        1
#>  6 plant_2        1
#>  7 plant_2        0
#>  8 plant_2        2
#>  9 plant_3        0
#> 10 plant_3        1
#> 11 plant_3        2
#> 12 plant_3        2
#> 13 plant_4        0
#> 14 plant_4        0
#> 15 plant_4        1
#> 16 plant_4        1
#> 17 plant_4        2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot, the thing is that I need all first rows to be deleted if they has the value "1". As you can see in my example. at group Planet_1, the rows that has left are only 3,4 and 5

Comment: Hi just to check before I update this you would want the last entry with each combination to still be in the dataframe?

Essentially the change would be to replace:
mutate(isfirst = 1:length(skipped) == 1) 
with:

Comment: What do you mean the last entry? I need everything to be the same beside that first set of rows that hold the value "1" if the appear in the beggining of each group.

Comment: Apologies but the skipped column contains 1s after the first list of 1s do you want these to remain in the dataset?

Comment: Yes. I've edited my example at my question so it will be more understanding, Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you for the updates I have adjusted the code accordingly. Please let me know if any additional problems or misunderstandings remain

Answer (score 1):

We could use the window function `cummin` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
test_df %>%  
  group_by(plant_sp) %>% 
  mutate(cummin = cummin(skipped)) %>% 
  filter(cummin == 0) %>% 
  select(-cummin)
```

Output:

```
   plant_sp skipped
   <chr>      <dbl>
 1 plant_1        0
 2 plant_1        1
 3 plant_1        2
 4 plant_2        0
 5 plant_2        1
 6 plant_2        1
 7 plant_2        0
 8 plant_2        2
 9 plant_3        0
10 plant_3        1
11 plant_3        2
12 plant_3        2
13 plant_4        0
14 plant_4        0
15 plant_4        1
16 plant_4        1
17 plant_4        2
```

Comment: Ingenious. I would not have thought it this way.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the most efficient way of handling this problem but here is another way:

```
test_df %>%
  group_by(plant_sp) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  filter(!(skipped == 1 & id == 1)) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  filter(!(skipped == 1 & id == 1)) %>%
  select(-id)

# A tibble: 17 x 2
# Groups:   plant_sp [4]
   plant_sp skipped
   <chr>      <dbl>
 1 plant_1        0
 2 plant_1        1
 3 plant_1        2
 4 plant_2        0
 5 plant_2        1
 6 plant_2        1
 7 plant_2        0
 8 plant_2        2
 9 plant_3        0
10 plant_3        1
11 plant_3        2
12 plant_3        2
13 plant_4        0
14 plant_4        0
15 plant_4        1
16 plant_4        1
17 plant_4        2
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you want to look at the row before, and see if there are any changes, and continue throughout the dataframe. I believe this can be done by looking at a lag and then filtering down to rows where the lagged value and current value differ. Assuming your dataframe is sorted as in your test, this should work:

```
test_df %>% 
  mutate(lag1 = coalesce(lag(plant_sp, 1), plant_sp),
         lag2 = coalesce(lag(skipped, 1), skipped)) %>% 
  filter(plant_sp == lag1 & lag2 != skipped) %>% 
  select(plant_sp, skipped)
```

Comment: Hey. thanks for you answer. It has merged all the rows in each group and changed my dataframe.